# Replace values in one column without NA

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I've a dataframe where I want replace some values in one column.
My column:

```
         col1
0         0.0
1 -89999991.0
2         1.0
3         2.0
4         0.0
5        11.0
```

I want to replace all values `<0 by 0` in col1 by using `df.loc[df.col1 <0, 'col2'] = 0`and write them into col2:

```
   col1
0   0.0
1   0.0
2   1.0
3   2.0
4   0.0
5  11.0
```

But the problem was that it replaced all  values by NAs:

```
  col2
0   NA
1  0.0
2   NA
3   NA
4   NA
5   NA
```

And I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to create a new columns col2 with all the positive values of col1 and 0 otherwise ? Or do you want to replace the negative values of col1 with 0.
Right now, you are creating a new column col2 with 0 where your col1 is negative.

Comment: By the looks, you seem to be clipping values less than 0, if so, you can use `df.clip(0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for replace by condition:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].mask(df.col1 <0, 0)
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['col2'] = np.where(df.col1 <0, 0, df['col1'])
print (df)
         col1  col2
0         0.0   0.0
1 -89999991.0   0.0
2         1.0   1.0
3         2.0   2.0
4         0.0   0.0
5        11.0  11.0
```

Another solution with [`clip_lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_lower.html):

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].clip_lower(0)
print (df)
         col1  col2
0         0.0   0.0
1 -89999991.0   0.0
2         1.0   1.0
3         2.0   2.0
4         0.0   0.0
5        11.0  11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

use `df.apply`

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: max(x,0))
```

Comment: Instead `df['col1'].clip(0)`, should be faster than `apply`